# Looking for a formula that states the stiffness of a composite

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, structural-engineering

I am looking for a formula that states the breaking point of a composite - How much pressure it can withstand before it 'snaps'. Specifically I am looking for a formula that states the materials stiffness.

Comment: What type of composite? Carbon fiber? Steel-concrete? Something else?

Comment: Hello Matt Welcome to Engineering SE. What is the Engineering problem that you need help? Have looked at wikipedia [Composite material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_material) I noticed that you posted a few questions.

Comment: All your questions lacks the necessary information required for community to provide a good response. I suggest that your read [How do I ask a good question?](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How can I ask a good question on Engineering.SE and receive quality responses?](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/287/how-can-i-ask-a-good-question-on-engineering-se-and-receive-quality-responses) I am voting to put your question on hold to enable you improve the question.

Comment: Hi Hazzey, don't have a specific material but it would be of a carbon matrix composite (CMC) materials. A CMC to my knowledge is where the matrix made of a ceramic material embedded between the fibres. i.e. carbon fiber embedded with carbon fibber (C/C)

Comment: I agree with Mahendra that this question should be edited to improve its quality. That being said, this question seems to be mixing up [strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strength_of_materials) and [stiffness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiffness). It would be important to clarify which of the two is being asked (or create another question regarding any doubts one has distinguishing between them, so long as the question follows the tips presented in the links given by Mahendra).

Comment: As a composite material expert - I can understand the poster's confusion.  I have some good tips and tricks to answer when the question is reopened, as strength and stiffness are very interrelated when calculating estimates for composite materials.  Ultimately, it's a broad subject, but it's hard to find anything comprehensive via google searches.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a formula. For metals, at least, these values are all derived empirically via extensive testing, such as [the Charpy V-notch test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charpy_impact_test), [tensile testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensile_testing), [fatigue testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatigue_(material)), etc. Typically you would find this information published in trade manuals or released by the manufacturer of the material.

If such a formula did exist, then couldn't you use it to solve for the "ultimate" composite material?