# How do I calculate an estimate for the properties of a composite material?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, composite

For a given laminate made of composite material (composed of fibers oriented in a carefully designed sequence coated and embedded in a matrix material), where can I begin estimating the stiffness and/or strength of the material?  How can I know (within a beginning estimate tolerance) how to design a part out of composite materials?

Comment: Is this designed to be a wiki page? Because you ask and then answer your own question which is [remarkably similar to one asked last weekend](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4128/looking-for-a-formula-that-states-the-stiffness-of-a-composite/4137#4137).

Comment: @Chuck [There isn't anything wrong with answering your own question.](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: @ChrisMueller - I understand, but there is a problem with asking duplicate questions. Why post a duplicate question and answer that one instead of answering the [original](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4128/looking-for-a-formula-that-states-the-stiffness-of-a-composite/)?

Comment: It'd be even better if I can get some edits to make this useful information for people of the future.

Comment: @chuck that question was written as to broad, and was closed as such. I tried to be in a realm of answerable questions while helping the original poster.

Comment: I've actually published a bit more professional version of this - I think this is good information that took me forever to find.  But, in case copyright issues come up I copied my own work.  >.<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to find out the stiffness and/or strength of a composite material, with a good understanding of the materials that make up the composite material.

**1. Pre-engineered composite materials**

Several materials, prevalent mainly in the aerospace industry, are pre-engineered and pre-designed.  [GY70/339](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=gy70+339+prepreg) is a common carbon fiber epoxy used extensively with highly tested properties.  The material is a [prepreg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-preg), which means the fibers are pre-oriented and the matrix to fiber ratio is carefully controlled in the factory selling the material.  The roll must be kept in careful thermal control to prevent the pre-impregnated roll from curing before desired.

**2. Simple formula used for rough estimation**

From a far enough point, a very simple [rule-of-mixtures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_mixtures) can be used for a lot of situations using composites.  This includes when one of the materials is even missing.  Unfortunately, the rule of mixtures can only figure out [stiffness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiffness), not [strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strength_of_materials).  Note the major differences in definition.  Most other methods for estimating materials can only measure stiffness, with strength being better defined as a maximum [strain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deformation_(mechanics)#Strain), then an actual strength.

**3. More complex empirical formula**

Beyond the rule of mixtures, there are more and more complex formulas that can be utilized.  For example, the [Halpin-Tsai](http://www.doitpoms.ac.uk/tlplib/fibre_composites/stiffness.php) formula is utilized frequently.  Although semi-empirical, it is used in plenty of applications that need good rough estimates to investigate the plausibility of a design.  More complex methods can be seen by various sources, but usually this is considered acceptable with follow up material testing.

**4. Highly complex formulas which still need testing**

State-of-the-art is considered [Mil Handbook 17F, Section 3, Chapter 5](https://www.library.ucdavis.edu/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/HDBK17-3F.pdf), which starts on page 211 of the reference.  Section 5.2 gives estimates for each layer, than 5.3 combines each layer into an orientation based laminate using matrix methods.  These are complex but understandable formulas.  As you get further into the document, you will notice that while this system is considered good enough for people who can't afford testing, stress concentration factors, fatigue factors, etc are completely unknown - if you need the system to be more reliable testing will be required, or you can use heavy safety factors and use these equations (10:1 is frequently used in pressure vessel applications, with 5:1 allowable for emergency circumstances, such as seismic and wind loading).

Hopefully this will be helpful to people asking "where do I begin" when it comes to composite material design.